# how to implement socket connection on server?

Tags: php, sockets

I am initiator of socket programming. I am trying to implement the socket connection.

But I don't know which IP and port should I use for server.

The code I took from a link :

server.php:

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = "<?>";
$port = 5555;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
//echo 'hello';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

   if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    exit;
} 
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
echo 'hello';
// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back
//$output = $_REQUEST['server_input'];
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>

 - client.php

<?php
//include_once('server.php');
$host    = "<?>";
$port    = 5555;
$message = "hi from client";
//echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);

?>
```

Description :

This function accepts incoming connection request on the created socket. After accepting the connection from client socket, this function returns another socket resource that is actually responsible for communication with the corresponding client socket. Here “$spawn” is that socket resource which is responsible for communication with client socket.

Comment: the following tutorial is a very hands on way to learn about socket programming. once you understand these basics, you should be able to do whatever you want armed with the manual. tutorial --> http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know which IP and port should I use for server.

The IP for use is same static IP set on your server's network, If you try to local test, Can use `127.0.0.1` for IP.
And also, for port, you can use one desired number between `1024` to `65535`.
Note that, the IP and Port used on the server and client must be same.